# The best way to sum up lots of numbers using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a large numbers of variables. What is the most correct way to calculate the sum. Below is the static way. .What if the numbers will increase to N times?

```
function abc(a,b,c,d){
  alert(a+b+c+d); 
}
abc(2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: Why don't you use an array instead of a large number of variables? Will make adding up easy.

Comment: Where are the numbers coming from? User input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `arguments`

```
function abc(){
  var total = 0;
  for( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     total += arguments[i];
  }
  alert(total);
}

abc(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQkTD/)

**OR**

```
function abc( args ){
  var total = 0;
  for( var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
     total += args[i];
  }
  alert(total);
}
abc([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQkTD/1/)

The best way would be to use the latter.

Comment: The `arguments` array isn't deprecated in strict mode, but strict mode [does change it and remove some behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode#Making_eval_and_arguments_simpler).

Comment: `arguments` haven't been deprecated or removed. `arguments.caller` was, but it was replaced with `arguments.callee.caller`

Comment: The `.arguments` property on a function object is prohibited in strict mode.

Comment: @JanDvorak: `arguments.callee` is also prohibited in strict.

Answer (score 4):

```
function abc(){
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function(a,b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
}
```

---

We can reduce the verbosity by binding `.reduce` as the `this` value of `.call`.

```
var reduce = Function.call.bind([].reduce);
```

Then it's just:

```
function abc(){
    return reduce(arguments, function(a,b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To accept a limitless number of arguments automatically, use [the `arguments` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments).

```
function sum() { // javascript functions can accept more arguments than specified
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    total += arguments[i];
  }
  return total;
}
```

Bear in mind that this might not actually be much shorter or more-readable than just calling "a + b + c + d" in your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shorter version using the `Array.reduce()` command.

```
function abc() {
   alert([].reduce.call(arguments, function(a, b) { return a + b; }));
}
abc(2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: Crazy Train posted the same solution while I was testing it.